# Joi validate specific fields based on larger schema

Tags: javascript, joi

Say I have the following schema

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  title: Joi.string().required(),
  start_date: Joi.date().iso().required(),
  end_date: Joi.date().iso().greater(Joi.ref('start_date')).required()
});
```

In one occasion I'd like to validate the entire schema against an object

```
const obj = {
  title: 'abc',
  start_date: '2021-11-09',
  end_date: '2021-11-10'
}
const validationResult = schema.validate(obj);
```

And on the other I'd like to validate against part of the schema with my partial object
(I don't want to be alarmed about a missing title, for instance)

```
const obj = {
  start_date: '2021-11-09',
  end_date: '2021-11-11'
}
const validationResult = schema/*sudo*/.onlyFields(['start_date', 'end_date']).validate(obj);
```

Is it possible?
Workaround is having 2 schemas - titleSchema and dateSchema and concatinating

Answer (score 2):

Solved using the `schema.extract` api

```
function joiSubSchema(base, fields) {
  return fields.reduce((schema, field) => {
    return schema.concat(Joi.object({
      [field]: base.extract(field)
    }));
  }, Joi.object());
}
```